# How can I copy all data-attrs to element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good day, I have HTML-object with some data-attributes. But I want to copy all the attributes to another item. As example:

```
<div data-attr-one="here is the data">content</div> <!-- This is an original item -->

<ul class="copied"></ul> <!-- This is a new item without data-attrs -->
```

I need have a **data-attr-one** in the **ul** item.

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Assign the div a class, or an id. Then use jQuery to find the desired elements, and use attr function to both get and set desired attributes. needless to say, you should do some javascript / jquery tutorials. this is pretty basic stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 var $div = $("div");
 var $ul = $("ul");

 var attributes = $div.prop("attributes");

 // loop through <select> attributes and apply them on <div>
 $.each(attributes, function() {
   $ul.attr(this.name, this.value);
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eSrv9/